# How to use a function from a file in a script tag in my react component

Tags: reactjs

I have `<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/course/capstone/master/api.js"></script>` in my index.html file and I want to use the functions within that file in my component but I keep getting the error that the function is undefined.

How to I uses functions that are inside a external file in my script tag in my components?

index.html File

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
    <meta
      name="description"
      content="Delicious, Organic Food"
    />
    <meta name="og:title" content="Restaurant"/>
    <meta name="og:description" content="Delicious, Organic Food"/>
    <meta name="og:image" content="%PUBLIC_URL%/restaurantfood.jpg"/>
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/logo192.png" />

    <link rel="manifest" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json" />
  
    <title>Restaurant title</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/course/api.js"></script>
    <div id="root"></div>
 
    
  </body>
</html>
```

contents of https://raw.githubusercontent.com/course/api.js

```
const seededRandom = function (seed) {
    var m = 2**35 - 31;
    var a = 185852;
    var s = seed % m;
    return function () {
        return (s = s * a % m) / m;
    };
}

const getDates = function(date) {
    let result = [];
    let random = seededRandom(date.getDate());

    for(let i = 17; i <= 23; i++) {
        if(random() < 0.5) {
            result.push(i + ':00');
        }
        if(random() < 0.5) {
            result.push(i + ':30');
        }
    }
    return result;
};

const submitDates = function(formData) {
    return true;
};
```

Trying to use `getDates()` or `window.getDates()` in a component file returns and error *'getDates' is not defined*